# Inserting values of field looped in a form to database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database

I am basically looping a set of fields multiple time through this

```
    <form name="insert_team" method="post" action="../includes/process.php?do=addteam">
            <table>
                <td style="width:40px;">Team:</td>
                <td id="data"><input type="text" name="team_name"/></td>
                <tr>
                <td>S.No</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Captain</td>
                <td>Category</td>
                <td>Batting Style</td>
                <td>Bowling Style</td>
                <td>Points</td>
                <tr>
                <?php
                for ($x=1;$x<2; $x++){
                ?>
                <td id="data"><?php echo $x ?> </td>
                <td id="data"><input name="player_name[]" type="text" value="abx"/></td>
                <td id="data">
                    <select style="width:50px;"name="is_captain[]"><option value="No">No</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td id="data">
                <select name="player_cat[]">
                <option value="Batsman">Batsman</option>
                <option value="Bowler">Bowler</option>
                <option value="Keeper">Wicket Keeper</option>
                <option value="All Rounder">All Rounder</option>
                </select>
                </td>
                <td id="data"><select style="width:160px;"name="bat_type[]">
                <option value="RHB">Right Hand Batsman</option>
                <option value="LHB">Left Hand Batsman</option>
                </select></td>
                <td id="data"><select name="bowl_type[]">
                <option value="Fast">Fast</option>
                <option value="Off Spinner">Off Spinner</option>
                <option value="Leg Spinner">Leg Spinner</option>
                <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                </select></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="points[]" value="20"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="status[]" hidden value="1" /></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                }
                ?>


            <td style="color:black;" colspan="6"><center><input type="submit"  style="background-color:#009900;"/></center></td>
            </table>

            </form>
                        </div>
        </center>

        </div>  
    </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

And here is the process.php which I am using to insert the value of each field in the database.

```
<?php session_start();

$from_Page = (string) $_REQUEST["do"];

require "dbcon.php";
require "func.php";
if( $from_Page=="addteam" ) {
    $team_name = $_POST["team_name"];
    echo $team_name;

    for ( $i=1; $i<2; $i++ ) {
        $player_name = $_POST["player_name"][$i];
        $category = $_POST["player_cat"][$i];
        $is_captain = $_POST["is_captain"][$i];
        $bat_type = $_POST["bat_type"][$i];
        $bowl_type = $_POST["bowl_type"][$i];
        $points = $_POST["points"][$i];
        $status = $_POST["status"][$i];
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_players (player_name,country_name,is_captain,category,bat_type,bowl_type,points,status) VALUES ($player_name,$team_name,$is_captain,$category,$bat_type,$bowl_type,$points,$status)";

    if (!$sql) 
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }

?>
```

I am still not able to insert data in the database, neither any errors are showing up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you running your query?

Comment: Not to mention where's the opening `<form>` tag for this? we don't know what method that's using.

Comment: then these are unknown `$from_Page=="addteam"` - `$_POST["team_name"]`

Comment: I skipped that part.. sorry.. kindly check now.

Comment: and as per your edit `?do=addteam` that suggests a GET method somewhere which is also unknown, as is the MySQL API used to connect with. So you're missing a `$_GET['do']` for it that looks to belong to `if( $from_Page=="addteam" )`.

Comment: and if any of these are strings, `($player_name,$team_name,$is_captain,$category,$bat_type,$bowl_type,$points,$status)` they need to be quoted. Best advice I can offer here, is for you to check for errors, which you're not. That alone would have thrown you syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

Should not you have any connection to your database to execute the query? Open the database connection using the following statement (assuming you are using mysql database):

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Then inside for executing the sql statement do following:

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Finally close the connection to the database:

```
$conn->close();
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp for more details

Comment: apologies for not mentioning, i am including my dbcon in the processs.php file already. I forgot to write the part in the question

Comment: @KuBitian85 - right. But there's still nothing in the code you've given _running the query_.